# App is not defined -undef ... starting new in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

i installed react , npm and fixed the PATH , wrote my first code and started the development server with npm and i get this :

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/App.js
> Line 5:1:    'hi' is not defined   no-undef
> Line 6:17:   'hi' is not defined   no-undef
> Line 10:16:  'App' is not defined  no-undef

my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

hi = <h1>Hello</h1>
ReactDOM.render(hi,document.getElementById('root'));
export default App
```

Comment: There is nothing to export. Remove the last line

Comment: tried that , gives a new error : ./src/index.js
Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').

Comment: try putting const before i.e const hi = <h1>Hello</h1>

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare the datatype. Also `export default App` are not required.

Comment: i tried to remove the last line and it gives this error :./src/index.js
Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').

Comment: Can you please show us the full code? We can't really tell whether you did or did not use <App/>. If you're using CRA (create-react-app), by right, there's a pre-defined App component regardless class component or functional component.

Comment: Also, if you're using CRA, by default it will import App. So the bottom line of your code should be something like ReactDOM.render(<App /> ,document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: i did use the CRA . thats the whole code (inside App file) i didnt edit or added any new files to src

Comment: If it is CRA, first, you forgot to _import App from "./App";_ in index.js and in your _App.js_ you forgot to _export default App;_

Comment: everything is in place , inside the index file here is the code :import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
and in App.js , export is the problem 
export default App

Comment: Can you please edit your question with code from all the files? I can't see the problem. As your code mentioned in the question doesn't indicate from which file (i.e App.js/index.js).

Comment: If the mentioned code in the question are from App.js, the App component are missing and ReactDOM.render(hi,document.getElementById('root')); are not required. Hence you got nothing to export or import because App went missing.

Comment: ok that actually makes a lot of sense , one question that is kind of related .....i tried to : export default 'App'; 
and it didnt give the error , it changed to warnings :
Compiled with warnings.

./src/App.js
  Line 1:17:  'Component' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars 
how does that work ? i can totally understand if you dont want to answer this question 
thanks for your time

Comment: If Component is defined but never used is probably because you're importing Component in import React, { Component } from "react". Back then when we're using class component, we need to declare something like this. class XXXXX extends Component{render(){}}

Comment: Remove {Component} from your import probably removed the warning.   =)

Answer (score 0):

1. You are trying to use `hi` before declaring it
2. you are exporting `App` without declaring it anywhere

Let's try

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

let hi = <h1>Hello</h1>
ReactDOM.render(hi,document.getElementById('root'));
// export default App 
// I am not sure you usage but since you already rendered it so i assume this line is not needed
```

Comment: i created this project with create-react-app 
what do you mean by declaring App

Comment: by default, your App.js should have something like `let App = XXX` or `function App` or even `class App`, but you removed it and made your own `hi`, so the `App` is undefined in that file

Comment: you're absolutely right , i shouldve paid more attention , cheers